Gitlab Workspaces Hot Reload Websocket connection error
I am trying to configure gitlab workspaces for a Remix project. I am struggeling with .devfile.yaml. I am tried to follow the info I gathered from devfile.io and official gitlab documentation. But I am unable to solve two problems:

Hot-reload for the remix project
Automatic execution of npm install upon opening the workspace environment.

My .devfile.yaml content:
    schemaVersion: 2.2.0
    variables:
      registry-root: registry.prd.x.de
    components:
      - name: app-dev-workspace
        attributes:
          gl/inject-editor: true
        container:
          image: "{{registry-root}}/x/app/workspace:latest"
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: development
          endpoints:
            - name: http-3000
              targetPort: 3000
            - name: websocket
              targetPort: 3001
              attributes:
                protocol: ws
                secure: true
                public: true
                type: ide
                discoverable: true
    commands:
      - id: init-project
        apply:
          component: app-dev-workspace
      - id: install-and-run-dev
        exec:
          component: app-dev-workspace
          commandLine: npm install --include=dev && npm run dev
          workingDir: $PROJECTS_ROOT
          group:
            kind: run
            isDefault: true

then in .env file I added following three things:
REMIX_DEV_ORIGIN="https://3001-workspace-40-4-1sbhxs.workspaces.prd.x.de"
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0

I either get error: Could not reach Remix dev server or The change you requested was rejected. Please contact your GitLab administrator if you think this is a mistake.
I have background from gitpod, in gitlab workspaces I am new. I am not sure how to check opened ports and if the configuration is working or not.
I appreciate all the help.
